# Codeigniter datamapper returns all rows instead of one

Tags: php, codeigniter

When i execute this code I got 2 as result instead of 1:

```
          $a = $this->load->model('account');
          //$a->where('id', $_POST['id'])->get(); also gives 2
          //$a->where('salt', $_POST['salt'])->get(); also gives 2
          // echo $_POST['id'] returns "2" as expected and $_POST['salt'] is also valid
          $a->where('id', $_POST['id'])->where('salt', $_POST['salt'])->get();
          echo $a->count(); // returns 2
```

But in my data base i have two rows with ids 1,2 and differents salts

Answer (score 1):

`$a->count()` is counting all rows in your table.

What you want is:

```
$result = $a->where('id', $_POST['id'])->where('salt', $_POST['salt'])->get();
echo count($result);
```

So that you are counting the number of rows returned by your query.